# Is there a command to list SVN conflicts?

Tags: svn

Does anyone know an SVN command to list current conflicts between the repo and the working copy?

Thanks

Answer (score 174, accepted):

On Linux, if you want to see only the conflicts, pipe the status through grep.

```bash
svn status | grep -P '^(?=.{0,6}C)'
```

Comment: Adding `-A 1` to the grep arguments will show you the line after the conflict line, which is sometimes related to the conflict.

Comment: @N13 +1 for the answer. It would be better if you describe it in detail. Like what is -P '^(?=.{0,6}C)'.

Comment: -P tells [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) to use perl regex, ^ = start of string, (?=) enclose the [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) pattern which is .{0,6} any 0 to 6 characters and the letter C, which is the indicator for conflicts

Comment: Pete's right. At a higher level, and unlike the other "^C" answers given, the lookahead lets the C appear anywhere in the first 7 columns/characters. It also implicitly allows more than one conflict per file. The columns are explained in the documentation for the status subcommand.

Comment: I keep referring to this answer. It should be printed at the top of relevant Google searches, like a definition.

Comment: Thanks, Jes. I actually put it in a bash alias so I wouldn't have to remember it. `alias svnconf="svn status | grep -P '^(?=.{0,6}C)'"`.

Comment: What is the point of using the lookahead part?  Couldn't `'^.{0,6}C'` work as well?

Comment: I think they are the same, in this case. Feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: To use this same command on OSX, you need to install GNU grep because the BSD grep doesn't have the perl regex flag (-P)

Comment: `'^.{0,6}[C>]'` will include the descriptions of tree conflicts ("local file edit, incoming file delete on merge" etc) as well as the list of files, if you want that. (This improves on the `-A 1` suggested by @WesleyHartford by only showing the following line if it's relevant)

Comment: On Windows the Powershell version of this is `(svn status) -Match '^(?=.{0,6}C)'`

Comment: @G.Rassovsky there's absolutely no need to install GNU tools when you can just use BSD grep for the same exact task.

Answer (score 31):

Just use grep!

```
svn st | grep '^C'
```

Comment: @sid, it's regexp for 'begins with,' so that means the first character is a C

Comment: I was thinking if this could miss files which have "A + C" status .. Is that an issue..

Comment: egrep '^[AC +]+' would do the trick then, though I don't usually have A+C issues.

Comment: Simple to keep in mind, and enough for most cases. Thanks @JosephLust.

Answer (score 11):

You could try `svn merge -r <revision> --dry-run` and see what happens that way.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Windows with svn 1.7.8. Error log: svn: E205001: Try 'svn help' for more info
svn: E205001: Merge source required

Answer (score 5):

If you have already merged you can use

```
svn status
```

and see an uppercase "C" for conflict, but usually you shouldn't see such kind in your working copy.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows PowerShell use:

```
svn status | sls -Pattern '^(?=.{0,6}C)'
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have ack from http://betterthangrep.com/, you can do the following

```
svn st | ack '^C'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's maybe possible to use `svn merge --dryrun` while specifying the repository URL with all revisions after the latest one you updated with.

E.g. if your current WC is based on revision 147 this could do it:

```
svn merge -r 148:HEAD http://url.to.repo/repo/
```

It's nothing I've done myself though, so you'll have to try it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't merged or updated files then use below command

`svn status --show-updates | grep -P '.*(?=.*M)(?=.*\*).*'`

**For short**

`svn st -u | grep -P '.*(?=.*M)(?=.*\*).*'`

**Details**
SVN don't mark conflict(C) status until you update the file(s) using `svn update`.
Until then statuses are shown like below

```
+---+------+---------------+---------------+
| M |      |               | 23246   file1 |
+---+------+---------------+---------------+
|   |      | *             | 23233   file2 |
+---+------+---------------+---------------+
| M |    * | 23233   file3 |               |
+---+------+---------------+---------------+
```

M   - Modified in local
*  - Updates/Incoming from remote
M and * - Modified in local, as well as in remote - **This is a conflict but svn haven't marked yet**

Answer (score -2):

on mac

```
$ svn status | grep -e '^!'
```

did the job

here is the man for grep:

> usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
>       [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
>       [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
>       [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: How's matching an exclamation mark going to help finding conflicted items?

Comment: `^!` is the regex for every line that begins with `!`. All the conflicted lines begin with `!`

Comment: No, I just solved conflicts on a 1.9 repo and the conflict lines were starting with just "C".